# Python - Get post data

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to make some python scripts on google appspot. I am just starting with python so I don't now verry much about it.

I am using the example code you can find on the google appspot documentations. But whenever I submit the form in this code, I just get an blank page and no errors. Anyone knows why?

```
import cgi

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):  

    def get(self):
      p = self.request.get("p", default_value="25")

      self.response.out.write("""
          <html>
            <body>
              <form action="/" method="post">
        The first <input type="text" name="p" value=""" + p + """ style="width: 35px;text-align:center;"> fibionacci numbers:<br />""")

      p = int(p)
      a, b = 0, 1
      while p > 0:
    self.response.out.write(str(b) + " ")
    a, b = b, a+b
    p = p - 1

      self.response.out.write("""
              </form>
            </body>
          </html>""")


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I won't help you with google apps, but if `form` is just a dictionary, than you can use `print form.keys()` to see what keys it holds; if it's of some other type, you can use `print dir(form)` to list it's internals or `help(form)` if it provides any documentation. dir and help are very useful when dealing with new libraries.

Comment: It's unusual that FieldStorage wouldn't pick up content in a POST, Would you mind editing your question to include the content of the form, as it appears in the HTML document?

Comment: Why are you trying to write a raw CGI app? There are many frameworks available, including the built-in webapp one, which will make writing a webapp a lot less painful than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOAH

If you're using google app engine (hosted on appspot so I'm sure that's what you're using) then you use this:

```
tPostVariable = self.request.get('PostVariableName')
```

If you've set up your handler like this then it will automagically work:

```
class ClassName(webapp.RequestHandler):
    #For Get Pages
    def get(self):
        tPostVariable = self.request.get('PostVariableName')

    #For Post Pages
    def post(self):
        tPostVariable = self.request.get('PostVariableName')
```

That will work for both GET and POST variables.

Comment: I have tried that, but then i get the following error:
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'self' is not defined Traceback

Comment: Make sure that your application is set up like the helloworld.py app in the example: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp.html

If you don't have the proper includes then I think it would likely cause that error.

Comment: def get(self) is for using the "get" method, or the request that happens when you load the page normally. Your form uses the post method so you'll have to define def post(self) also.

Comment: If this solved your problem then please flag it as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You catch `NameError`. It throws `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested approach to read keys which exist or do not exist is:

```
p = form.get('p', '0') # 0 = default value
try:
    p = int(p)
except ValueError, e:
    pass # What do do when p is not an integer?
```